# How to add new values for custom types using Entity Framework Migrations?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, .net-core, entity-framework-core, entity-framework-migrations

I have let's say an entity named `User` with an Enum type property named `user_type` with the following values: `admin` and `editor`.

I want to add a new value to this Enum: `contributor`, but I'm not able to make Entity Framework generate the script to update the Enum type with the new value.

I have:

```cs
// The Enum itself
public enum UserType : byte
{
  admin,
  editor,
  contributor
}

//Entity class
public class User
{
  [Column("user_type")]
  [Required]
  public UserType UserType { get; set; }
}

// My DbContext class
static MyDbContext()
{

  NpgsqlConnection.GlobalTypeMapper.MapEnum<UserType>("user_type");

}
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{

  modelBuilder.ForNpgsqlHasEnum("user_type", new[] { "admin", "editor", "contributor" });

  modelBuilder.Entity<UserType>();

}
```

When I run the command:

```bash
dotnet ef migrations script --idempotent PREVIOUS_MIGRATION_NAME CURRENT_MIGRATION_NAME --output CURRENT_MIGRATION_NAME.sql
```

I don't see anything about altering the type with the new value. I would have expected something like:

```sql
ALTER TYPE user_type ADD VALUE 'contributor'
```

I'm using .NET Core 3.1 and Entity Framework Core .NET Command-line Tools 6.0.5

Comment: So postgresql enums? https://www.npgsql.org/efcore/mapping/enum.html?tabs=tabid-1 I'm not seeing an `ForNpgsqlHasEnum` extension method?

Comment: Yeah Postgresql enums. For some reason method doesn't show in the docs. However the above migration code/configuration works if you add a new Enum; just that updating an existing Enum does not work.